# SHA return different result i MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, sha256

I have a table that is filled with some value, for setting the value I use a stored procedure that also calculate a hash function and save in database.
In case of updating value hash should be recalculated. For recalculating hash I use the following procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_UpdateHash`(IN rkey int)
Begin
DECLARE AuthCode VarChar(10);

SET @input = concat('SELECT r_ac into @AuthCode
    FROM table_rec
    where r_key=',rkey);

PREPARE squery FROM @input;
EXECUTE squery;
SET @hashed = SHA2(@AuthCode,256);
select @hashed;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE squery;
end;
```

and procedure just for calculating hash:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_GetHash`(IN AuthCode VarChar(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE hashed VarChar(64);
    SET hashed = SHA2(AuthCode,256);
    select hashed as 'Hash';
END
```

AuthCode identical, but hash is different when I try to process value after select command I get a wrong code. If I compare two hashes with other results, for example from an online generator, the result is similar to the second function: sp_GetHash

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=da7b0feebee3775de4a02e1cfc5b6a1e).

Comment: For the second one, simplify to a function with this body: `RETURN SHA2(AuthCode, 256);`.  The first proc can be cut in half.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in one field that has a different coding from the table, and when I use it in the query it has a different size.